# Wordpress resolves get_template_directory_uri() with fullqualified http://localhost/ instead relative

Tags: wordpress

I've installed wordpress in my xampp environment. All my CSS and JS in my theme are included via:

```
wp_enqueue_style('kiga_spottberg_pure', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/pure/pure-min.css', array(), null);
```

Now is tho problem that in my html source code on every place the full uri was printed:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='kiga_spottberg_pure_grids-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/kiga_spottberg/bower_components/pure/grids-min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

But this don't work if I access my local server via IP address. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your blog url in Settings -> General or set the a dynamic site url by following the [instructions from the WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#wp_siteurl) docs.